# What are the rules for hosts playing dead?

Tags: westworld-2016

In *Westworld*, if a host is shot, they fall down and are effectively "dead" until they are repaired and reactivated. But we have seen several scenes where this is overridden with a simple voice command, a "dead" host reactivates. We have also seen that in certain circumstances hosts can simply ignore gunshot wounds and keep going unimpeded - both Hector and Dolores have demonstrated this capability ("we were designed to survive"). We also know see that "dead" hosts have been reactivated over the mesh network by Mæve.

What are the "rules" governing this behaviour, and why don't those with the appropriate command authority override it more often? For example, we often see techs carrying "dead" hosts around... Why not just order them to walk? And why do hosts that have "awoken" not use this ability themselves (with few exceptions that do)?

Comment: The job of the techs is to determine the extent of the damage to the host and repair it before re-activating them. Presumably ordering them to move around could injure them further, making the job of repairing them harder. It's the same reason repair garages use 'car transporters' to move vehicles that have been in accidents rather than just driving them.

Comment: Dragging them around by their feet then throwing them on a pile would damage them further too! It's clearly shown that the majority of techs have zero regard for the hosts, even as delicate machinery.

Comment: Sure, but external problems can be dealt with using patch-spray. Internal problems require the robotic equivalent of surgery

Comment: @Gaius - I can not verify this, but my assumption has always been that it falls in line with their programmed tasks. If they are following their story they die and remain so until reactivated; whether it be from Maeve, a tech, etc. If they are not following a story line then all bets are off. A host still can take enough damage that they can no longer function, which is why Lee stays behind instead of Hector during his last stand, but as they have no 'vital organs' they can withstand much more damage and continue to function. Great point about having a dead host walk themselves though...